# How to apply mandatory to choose an option in matlab?

Tags: matlab

First of all sorry if the question is not being well specified because I don't know how exactly to describe it. My question is as follow

let k = menu('a','b','c');

if k > 0

> program continue

else

> terminate the program and disp('please select an option')
>   and the menu function will pop up again for the use to select.

how can I program this situation? thank you for anyone that kindly to give an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you have described you can use error()

```
if K <= 0
    error("Please select option")
end

%The rest of your code here:
```

But it would make more sense to rather set up a while loop that waits for a correct user input:

```
    while k <= 0
        let k = menu('a', 'b', 'c') % I don't fully understand how you are setting k, but that bit goes here

        if k <= 0
            disp('please select an option');
        end
    end

% The rest of your code here
```

Comment: Ic...it helped man..thanks...between can I ask is it possible for us to insert a legend in our 'menu' function.

Comment: means k = menu('a','b','c');
then I can insert a=amplitude in the pop up menu

Comment: You should rather post a new question about the menu legend

Comment: well...I had created a new question but unfortunately no one answering..@Dan can you help me?